# Run Detached Bokeh Server

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, bokeh

I'm trying to run a bokeh server within a Docker container but bokeh doesn't allow me to enter commands while the server is running.  Is there a way to run the server detached so that I can enter other commands while the page is up?  I'm using a (slightly modified) ubuntu image with python3 for this container.

If anyone happens to also know why I wouldn't be able to access the page from my host machine after exposing the ports that'd be even better-that's the larger issue I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line:

```
bokeh serve --show --allow-websocket-origin=localhost:5006 file_name.py
```

Put the following at the end of the dockerfile to run the command above and be able to access the app your trying to host:

```
CMD ["bokeh","serve","--show","--allow-websocket-origin=localhost:5006","file_name.py"]
```